# Does a timer keep firing in a mobile browser after the device is put to sleep?

Tags: javascript

I have a repeating timer on a page. If the page is being viewed on a mobile device (like iphone), and the user sleeps the phone, does the browser keep executing the timer?

I'm worried about users leaving this page open, sleeping the phone, then the timer just keeps firing forever until they close the page or navigate away from it.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that depends purely on the phone.

Comment: I'm very sure the timer will be stopped, or at least paused. But anyway, this is easy to test, increase a number on a timer and make the number visible on the page.

Comment: You could catch the `blur` event and stop the counter timeouts manually

Answer (score 2):

I also think it stops, but just to make sure why not leverage the Visibility API?  The page is certainly not visible if the activity is not showing or the user is using another tab.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/